# How to show images from device storage in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, imagesource

I need to set the `Source` property of an image to the path returned after the user has picked it from gallery or camera (using Plugin.Media) 
the path looks like this:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.company.myApp/files/Pictures/temp/Screenshot_20181225-134128_6.jpg
```

I tried this

```
ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(file.FilePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

but the image doesn't show anything,

Comment: any Exception in the Console or logcat?

Comment: Do you have permissions for external files: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=windows

Answer (score 0):

Media Plugin returns a file with the path. You have to use this, for the file:

```
image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
    {
        var stream = file.GetStream();
        return stream;
    });
```

Comment: No, I don't want to use `FromStream`, 
not good with data binding.

Comment: You can use it in your ViewModel populating a model contains ImageSource, so the Data Binding will be ok.

Comment: this exception is thrown: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'Stream has been closed'.

Comment: Copy the file Stream to MemoryStream and use it from there.

Answer (score 0):

you can create an object of MediaFile like,

`public MediaFile AttachedImage;`

and store captured image into it so that your below issue will resolved,
**this exception is thrown: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'Stream has been closed**.
you can get Image Stream any time from that object like,

```
img.Source = AttachedImage.GetStream().
```

it will sure resolve your issue.